# wrong toolchain of QT in cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I am trying to build project which has capabilities of being build cross platform.
As such it requires multiple versions of QT as its dependancy. It has 3 versions of qt to be more precise:

- gcc_64
- android_x86
- android_armv7

I am trying to build on linux so I am expecting the gcc_64 to be selected.
However when I

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5OpenGL REQUIRED)
```

The ccmake seems to be picking the  android_armv7.
The paths which I am geting are following:

> Qt5OpenGL_DIR                    /opt/apps/Qt/5.6/android_armv7/lib/cmake/Qt5OpenGL

And this bring me to the question, is there a method of influencing the cmake to find specific alternative?

If this is dependant on some variable which is specifying the target platform/arch/toolchain, it is entirely likely that it is wrongly set so if you know what might be causing the wrong version to be selected please point me in the direction of the wrong flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can manipulate the include with DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to affect the version found. This + cleaning cmake cache resolved issue fro me.

I have passed it to cmake as:

> -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/apps/Qt/5.6/gcc_64

Comment: Yesterday, I just stumbled into a similar issue. After installing Qt5, and CMake on my Windows 10 laptop, I tried to prepare a minimal Qt5 project. CMake complained about missing Qt5 until I prepared an environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and the resp. Qt5 path (which had to be the parent folder of the resp. Qt5 `bin` folder according to my intended dest. platform.) After having set this env. var. properly, CMake started to build the solution/projects.